# How do I give ENV['DATABASE_URL'] to Whenever gem in Fly.io Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cron, whenever, fly

I'm trying to use the [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem in my Rails app to schedule some rake tasks.

I'm hosting the app on Fly.io, and the rakes are aborting because they can't connect to the Postgres database in the production environment.

I wondered if the credentials stored in the secrets were somehow wrong; to troubleshoot this, I deleted the database and set up a new one, and set the secrets (username, URL, password) which are meant to be accessible in the ENV['DATABASE_URL'] environment variable.

I understand that the ENV['DATABASE_URL'] takes precedence over the database.yml file when it's present. I've tried all sorts of configurations, currently I have this in my schedule.rb file:

`env :DATABASE_URL, ENV['DATABASE_URL']

set :environment, :production`

And this in my database.yml file:

`production: <<: *default`

But I still get the following errors in my cron.log file:

`rake aborted! ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "thomaskitson" does not exist /Users/thomaskitson/code/tkitson/newsguessr/rails-authentication/lib/tasks/newspaper.rake:17:in` block (2 levels) in '
/Users/thomaskitson/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/bundle:25:in `load' /Users/thomaskitson/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/bundle:25:in` '

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "thomaskitson" does not exist
/Users/thomaskitson/code/tkitson/newsguessr/rails-authentication/lib/tasks/newspaper.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <main>' /Users/thomaskitson/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/bundle:25:in` load'
/Users/thomaskitson/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>' Tasks: TOP => newspaper:new_images (See full trace by running task with --trace)`

"thomaskitson" is not the name of the database, so I don't know why it's searching for one called that. There is an env variable called DATABASE_URL present in the fly secrets, so I believe that this is set up properly. Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Surprised to learn it takes precedence over database.yml if that's true I think the file would either have to be not present or at least not have the% relevant environment omitted Big point of confusion for me too Possibly you could have just ```database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>``` for the relevant environment in database.yml and omit everything else

Comment: I think that's true: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#connection-preference